# how to put the result of my mysql query to the option tag?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a database user with a table `user(name(varchar(25)),status(int(1))`. The values in status will be just `1` or `0`. My query is `select user.name where status=1` and I just want the result of it to be put in the option tag. I have tried the codes below but it only appears the select box and no options.

```
<select>
<?php 
include'connect.php';
$res = mysql_query("SELECT name from user where status=1 ");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
?>
<option value="<?=$row['name']?>"><?=$row['name']?></option><?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Change `$res` to `$row`

Comment: `<option value="<?php $row['name']?>"><?php $row['name']?></option><?php } ?>`

Comment: okay. i revised it like that already. but it is still not working

Comment: remove `=` after `<?` and keep a space after `php` opening tag and always try to avoid using short opening tags and use long one instead (`<?php`) to make sure ur app will work under any `php` configuration

Comment: try $res = mysql_query("SELECT name user where status='1'") or die(mysql_error()); to see if there is any errors with the query

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this. Note you are doing a `while` returning `$row` but your original code was referencing `$res['name']`.  It should all be `$row` with `$row['name']` being set in the `<option>` now:

```
<select>
<?php 
include 'connect.php';
$res = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM user WHERE status='1'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
  echo '<option value="' . $row['name'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```

Also note how I am creating a whole PHP block to run through the results. This makes more sense, is easier to read & easier to debug when compared to template formatting where PHP code snippets are mixed in with HTML.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'name' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: I've seen that you've edited it. but it's still not working.. the only thing that appear is the select box. and no options

Comment: i have tried it without the select and option tags the result is this.. @jakegould what does this warning mean? **Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given**

Comment: You forgot the "from" in the query, try "SELECT name FROM user where status='1'"